# How does a key knob by scenebuilder

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

how can use this controller "Knop" in my project ?
It is located in an interface scenebuilder ??
[image]

Comment: Custom control of SceneBuilder. You need to implement it for yourself.

Comment: @M.leRutte That's not accurate. The SceneBuilder app contains an open source kit library with a bunch of controls that you can reuse in your projects.

Comment: oh, whow! have a link?

Comment: @M.leRutte See my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a control from the SceneBuilder *Kit*, a library that is used by the SceneBuilder *App*.

If you go to Gluon's SceneBuilder download [site](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/), you can find the SceneBuilder kit jar, and the following info:

> Scene Builder Kit is used by IDE developers and people involved in creating tooling. It allows for Scene Builder to be embedded into these tools in a cohesive way, such that it becomes part of the tool. Most users will not want to download this - stick to Scene Builder itself.

So you can download it from [here](http://gluonhq.com/download/scene-builder-kit/), or from the Gluon public [repository](http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/scenebuilder-kit/) if you use Maven or Gradle (`'com.gluonhq.scenebuilder:scenebuilder-kit:8.4.0'`).

Once you have added the library to your project, you can find the "knob" in the `com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.util.control.paintpicker.rotator.RotatorControl` class.

A very simple use case:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    RotatorControl rotator = new RotatorControl("Rotate");

    Scene scene = new Scene(rotator, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image: Rotator]

By the way, the knob itself is a pair of buttons with some css styling, so you can also learn from how is it done in the class [source code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/src/1f5a1f5335f64f5041b730842b6c53bf26c4054a/kit/src/main/java/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/util/control/paintpicker/rotator/RotatorControl.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Comment: The control will give you -180 to 180º. You can listen to the control's `rotationProperty()` changes and then convert the value as you need. You could also hide the built-in `TextField` node (visible and managed set to false), and add your own textfield to display the `rotationProperty` with your own conversion. And of course, based on the control source code, you could easily create your own control with the required adjustments.

Comment: i know change this methods to crate my control 
    void rotatorMouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 

But what do I change to get degrees from 0-360 
Thank you

Comment: If you mean how to set the control to have 0º East, 90º N, 180º W and 270º S, then you can do something like `toDegrees = Math.toDegrees(- radians);`, checking that `if (toDegrees < 0)` then `toDegrees += 360;`. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: thank you, but how we can flip it to be counterclockwise?

Comment: The change I proposed will give you exactly counterclockwise.

Comment: this is my code:      final Double deltaX = mouse.getX() - center.getX();
        final Double deltaY = mouse.getY() - center.getY();
        final Double radians = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
        if (Math.toDegrees(-radians) < 0){
         rotateAngel=Math.toDegrees(radians)+360;
         rotate(Math.toDegrees(radians)+360);
        }else{
         rotateAngel=Math.toDegrees(radians);
            rotate(Math.toDegrees(radians));
        }
    }

Comment: here ?
     rotateAngel=Math.toDegrees(radians);
        rotate(Math.toDegrees(radians));

        if (Math.toDegrees(radians) < 0){
         rotateAngel=Math.toDegrees(radians)+360;
         rotate(Math.toDegrees(radians)+360);
        }

but this clockwise , i need this control  counterclockwise

Comment: Note my comment, I did change the sign of radians: `toDegrees = Math.toDegrees(- radians);`, but your code is not taking into account that change.